# Connecting Attribute Fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes

I am working with a wildlife-related feature class where I have different fields for common name (i.e. Northern Goshawk), scientific name (Accipiter gentilis), and species code (NOGO). I have domains for all of these which limits acceptable answers to only the species that occur in the area studied. However, as I'm essentially adding the same information 3 times per data point, any species code I enter will only match up with one common name and one scientific name. Is there a way to link these fields so when I enter one field information (say, NOGO) the other two auto-fill?

I'm quite new to geodatabases.

Comment: I doubt that you need populate all 3. Keep look up table that you can join to feature table and if necessary populate missing info by click of a mouse using field calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using [subtypes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/subtypes/an-overview-of-subtypes.htm).

They will assign values to dependent fields based on the subtype value.